# I want to upload to youtube with youtube-api without notification

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I created the code using the official youtube reference.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

However, it didn't say anything about setting up notifications for channel subscribers.
I want to turn off notifications to subscribers.

Is it not possible to set this in the youtube-API?
Or is it written?
If you have any instructions on how to set up notifications to be switched off, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You may have miss understood the purpose of the YouTube Data api.

> With the YouTube Data API, you can add a variety of YouTube features to your application. Use the API to upload videos, manage playlists and subscriptions, update channel settings, and more.

The YouTube Data api is not designed to help you manage your channel.

There is no method that will let you control notifications for subscribers of a channel.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation you linked. The Videos.insert() API call has `notifySubscribers` optional parameter. If you set that to False you will not notify your subscribers. [Documentation you also quoted](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)